# Mongoexport to multiple csv files

Tags: mongodb, csv, export-to-csv, mongoexport

I have a large mongoDB collection. I want to export this collection to CSV so I can then import it in a statistics package to do data analysis.

The collection has about 15 GB of documents in it. I would like to split the collection into ~100 equally sized CSV files. Is there any way to achieve this using mongoexport? I could also query the whole collection in pymongo, split it and write to csv files manually, but I guess this would be slower and would require more coding.

Thank you for input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using `--skip` & `--limit` options.

For example, if you that your collection holds 1,000 document you can do it using a script loop (pseudo code):

```
loops = 100
count = db.collection.count()
batch_size = count / loops

for (i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    mongoexport --skip (batch_size * i) --limit batch_size --out export${i}.json ...
}
```

Taking into account that your documents are roughly equal in size.

Note however, that large skips are slow.

Lower bound iterations will be faster than upper bound iterations.

Comment: 10M skips take at least 12 hours (none still finished). Beware of using Mongo for any serious project.

Answer (score 0):

Better version of above loop that does it all in parallel because you're an impatient sonnofabitch like I am:

presume we have 385892079 records, divide that by 100.

`let bs=3858920
for i in {1..100}
do 
let bsi=${bs}*$i
mongoexport --db dbnamehere --collection collectionNamehere --port 3303\
  --fields="f1,f2,f3" \
  --out /opt/path/to/output/dir/dump.${i}.json -v \
  --skip ${bsi} --limit ${bs} 
done`

Answer (score 0):

```
#total=335584
limit=20974;
skip=0;
for i in {1..16}; do mongoexport --host localhost --db tweets --collection mycollection --type=csv --fields tweet_id,user_name,user_id,text --out master_new/mongo_rec_${i}.csv -v --skip ${skip} --limit ${limit} --quiet; let skip=$((skip+limit)); done
```