# mongodb: export collection into multiple files

Tags: mongodb

I have a 10GB collection in mongoDB, how can I export the entire collection into multiple json files. For example, 2GB or half million documents each file.

version I'm using: mongoldb 3.6.3

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) to do this, e.g. like this:

```
mongoexport -d database -c collection --sort '{_id: 1}' --limit 100 --skip 100 --out output.json
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

> mongodump is a utility for creating a binary export of the contents of a database. mongodump can export data from either mongod or mongos instances.

**Example:**

```
mongodump  --db test --collection collection -o dirname
```

Where test is database that you are creating dump of, and collection is collection that you want to dump(collection is optional). dirname is output directory you want to do dump in

Comment: This does not answer the question: how do you export a collection to multiple files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29082031/9450101
This should be the answer to the question